# Pandas replace seem not to work with inplace=True and no assignment

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I am a beginner in pandas and I met this problem recently.

with the data below(few lines ahead)

```
          Country  Energy Supply  Energy Supply per Capita  % Renewable
0     Afghanistan   3.210000e+08                      10.0    78.669280
1         Albania   1.020000e+08                      35.0   100.000000
2         Algeria   1.959000e+09                      51.0     0.551010
3  American Samoa            NaN                       NaN     0.641026
4         Andorra   9.000000e+06                     121.0    88.695650
```

I wish to read in the data from excel, set the names of the columns, then ***replace the names of certain countries*** in a function then return the Dataframe for further use.

```
def answer_one():
    energy = pd.read_excel('Energy Indicators.xls',skiprows=18,header=None,skipfooter=38,parse_cols='C:F')
    energy.columns = ['Country', 'Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', '% Renewable']
    energy.replace('...',np.nan,inplace=True)
    energy['Energy Supply'] = energy['Energy Supply'] * 1000000
    energy.replace({"Republic of Korea": "South Korea",
    "United States of America": "United States",
    "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland": "United Kingdom",
    "China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region": "Hong Kong"},inplace=True)
    energy.replace(regex={r'[0-9]':'',r'\(.*\)':''},inplace=True)

    return energy
answer_one()
```

for the regex match, it works perfectly, but

```
energy['Country'].replace({"Republic of Korea": "South Korea",
    "United States of America": "United States",
    "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland": "United Kingdom",
    "China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region": "Hong Kong"},inplace=True)
```

It does not seem to work. Then in the result of the function returned Dataframe, I notice that:

```
216 United States of America    9.083800e+10    286.0   11.570980
```

So the value is not correctly replaced

Why is this happening? I'll be much appreciated if you could help understand this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I working with similar data I think I know problem.

There are sometimes superscripts numbers after country names, so need swap code for first remove numbers and then replace strings:

```
energy.replace(regex={r'[0-9]':'',r'\(.*\)':''},inplace=True)
energy.replace({"Republic of Korea": "South Korea",
"United States of America": "United States",
"United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland": "United Kingdom",
"China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region": "Hong Kong"},inplace=True)
```

---

I think `inplace` is not good practice, check [this](https://www.dataschool.io/future-of-pandas/#inplace) and [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529).

So better is use:

```
d = {"Republic of Korea": "South Korea",
     "United States of America": "United States",
     "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland": "United Kingdom",
    "China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region": "Hong Kong"}

energy = energy.replace(regex={r'[0-9]':'',r'\(.*\)':''})
energy['Country']= energy['Country'].replace(d)
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked! But why is that removing the superscript numbers first then replace could solve the problem. I mean isn't is just the matter of order?

Comment: @朱原昊 - I think problem was if no `regex=True` in `replace`, then it not replace subtrings. so another solution is use `energy['Country']= energy['Country'].replace(d, regex=True)` and then `energy = energy.replace(regex={r'[0-9]':'',r'\(.*\)':''})`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
energy['Country']= energy['Country'].replace({"Republic of Korea": "South Korea",
    "United States of America": "United States",
    "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland": "United Kingdom",
    "China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region": "Hong Kong"},inplace=True)
```